# Minor version of a java class file

Tags: java

What is the use of minor version in a a java  class file? Is it really used till now?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html

Comment: I missed following point in the spec Oracle's Java Virtual Machine implementation in JDK release 1.0.2 supports class file format versions 45.0 through 45.3 inclusive. JDK releases 1.1.* support class file format versions in the range 45.0 through 45.65535 inclusive. For k ≥ 2, JDK release 1.k supports class file format versions in the range 45.0 through 44+k.0 inclusive."

Comment: Basically Oracle JDK not planning to change minor version  from java 1.2 onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed following point in the spec

"Oracle's Java Virtual Machine implementation in JDK release 1.0.2 supports class file format versions 45.0 through 45.3 inclusive. JDK releases 1.1.* support class file format versions in the range 45.0 through 45.65535 inclusive. For k ≥ 2, JDK release 1.k supports class file format versions in the range 45.0 through 44+k.0 inclusive."

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 11 [JEP 12](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/12), "Preview Language and VM Features" is available. Classes using preview features have a minor_version number of `0xFFFF`.

> A class file denotes that it depends on the preview VM features of Java SE $N by having a major_version item that corresponds to Java SE $N and a minor_version item that has all 16 bits set. For example, a class file that depends on the preview VM features of Java SE 13 would have version 57.65535

So, here the minor_version is used. I am not aware of any other usage of the minor_number, in all other cases it is `0x0000` (expect for the oldest Java versions, up to version 1.1, where the minor_version is set to `0x0003`).